# meta viewport = behave as unset

Tags: html

Google wants me to add the viewport meta tag to my pages.  I've tried stuff like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But that breaks the design.  Can I set the viewport to behave in the same way as when it is unset in that it zooms all the way out to encompass the entire design?

Switching to a "responsive design" is something I would like to consider later.  For now I would like to band-aid this.

Comment: Is it fair to say this is not possible if I don't want to set a static pixel width for my site?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a specific width...such as:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

And experimenting to what works for your site best.

Comment: Would my site's width still expand and contract according to the width of the browser?

Comment: It shouldn't - it should stay as it is coded.  This code is not responsive.